# Json unmarshal: force into string

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have the following Go struct into which I want to unmarshal some Json data. It works perfectly except for the `Values` map, which is of type `map[string]string`.

```
type Data struct {
    Id          int               `jons:"id"`
    Values      map[string]string `json:"values"`
```

My Json data (which I can't change the format of), has the following structure and sample data:

```
{
   id: 1,
   values: {
      key1: "a string value",
      key2: 7
   }
}
```

Unmarshalling the json data fails because Go can't unmarshal the value `7` into a string.

```
json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field Data.Values of type string
```

Is there a way to implicitly convert the Json values into a string, regardless of the perceived type?
Changing the Json data to format the value as a string, ie `key2: "7"` is not an option.

Comment: Your JSON does not have a field named "values" (and it's not even well-formed); care to provide an [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/720999)?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I had to “anonymize” the code. Fixed it now.

Comment: and I assume you can't change the type of the map either? `map[string]int`

Comment: @blackgreen I can but then I won’t be able to unmarshal string values. Converting the int value from the JSON data to string makes sense in my use case. But there’s no way to convert a string value to int that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can have an integer or a string in the json, it would be better if you use an interface.

Something like this:

```
type Data struct {
    Id          int                       `jons:"id"`
    Values      map[string]interface{}    `json:"values"`
}
```

This should do the trick.

Sample code for reference:
https://play.golang.org/p/PjxWeLTwsCC

Comment: To add, after using interface{} to parse the value, it still cannot be used for string operations. The bottom layer still holds the int type, and key2.(string) fails. You can pass fmt.Sprintf("%v", key2 ) To use as a string

Answer (score 2):

You can create own string type and implement UnmarshalJSON function to it.

```golang
type MadSrting string

type Data struct {
    Id          int                  `jons:"id"`
    Values      map[string]MadString `json:"values"`
}

func (mad *MadString) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if n := len(data); n > 1 && data[0] == '"' && data[n-1] == '"' {
        return json.Unmarshal(data, (*string)(mad))
    }   
    
    *mad = MadString(data)

    return nil
}
```

Sample: https://play.golang.org/p/PsJRsvQJPMZ

Comment: You should use `json.Unmarshal` on `data` if it contains a string rather than just trimming the surrounding quotes to properly unmarshal escaped chars in the string. e.g. https://play.golang.org/p/m_XNP5di26X vs https://play.golang.org/p/eOuVYubPv9B.

Comment: @mkopriva, agree. I will edit answer with your fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use interface and type assertions

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    type Data struct {
        Id          int               `jons:"id"`
        Values      map[string]interface{} `json:"values"`
    }

    jsonData := []byte(`{"id": 1, "values": {"key1": "a string value", "key2": 7}}`)

    data := new(Data)
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    for _, value := range data.Values {
        fmt.Printf("%T\n", ToString(value))
    }
}

func ToString(value interface{}) string {
    str := ""

    switch value.(type) {
    case float64:
        str = strconv.FormatFloat(value.(float64), 'f', 0, 64)
    case int64:
        str = strconv.FormatInt(value.(int64), 10)
    case int:
        str = strconv.Itoa(value.(int))
    case string:
        str = value.(string)
    }

    return str
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/r9_6IKRgPst

Answer (score 1):

To round up the provided answers, there exist basically three approaches:

1. Use a map of custom-typed values, whose type "wraps" `string` and implements an `encoding/json.Unmarshaler` interface to be creative about how it parses the values from the JSON document.
2. Unmarshal the subdocument into a map of type `map[string]interface{}` and then either use type-switching on the value on each access to such value or populate some other data type — supposedly `map[string]string` in your case — *from* the resulting map (you'll be using type-switching in either case).
3. Use a lower-level JSON decoding facilities — [`encoding/json.Decoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json#Decoder) — and make decision about how to decode a particular value at decoding phase, and produce a `string` no matter which type the value being parsed really is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the empty interface on your maps values. An then convert it to a string with Sprintf. Here is an example of how you could unmarshal your data:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Data struct {
    Id     int                    `jons:"id"`
    Values map[string]interface{} `json:"values"`
}

func main() {
    data := `
{
    "id": 1,
    "values": {
        "key1": "a string value",
        "key2": 7
    }
}
`
    var d Data
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &d)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(d)

    s1 := fmt.Sprintf("%v", d.Values["key1"])
    fmt.Println("key1", s1)

    s2 := fmt.Sprintf("%v",  d.Values["key2"])
    fmt.Println("key2", s2)
}
```